# How to create an Azure Service Principal for an existing SQL server resource

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-service-principal, service-principal

I need to create a new Azure Service Principal that will be associated with an existing SQL server resource via PowerShell. An unknown person in the company has done this manually before, and I can see that the SQL server's `identity.principalId` property is used for the Service Principal's `ObjectId`. Unfortunately, I have not been able to find documentation for how to create this via PowerShell.

I am aware of the [`New-AzADServicePrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadserviceprincipal?view=azps-9.2.0) command, and I suspect that the `-ApplicationObject` property is what I should pass the SQL server info in. I'm wondering if this line of thinking is correct, and how to use `-ApplicationObject` property to represent my SQL server.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-service-principal-tutorial?view=azuresql#assign-an-identity-to-the-azure-sql-logical-server) I was looking for. Using the following command on an existing SQL server seems to implicitly create a Service Principal Identity of the same name as the SQL server

`Set-AzSqlServer -ResourceGroupName <resource group> -ServerName <server name> -AssignIdentity`